# Compose transformable breaks verticalScroll

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) {
    val transformableState = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, _, _ -> }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().transformable(state = transformableState)) {
        //scrollable content goes here
    }
}
```

with Compose UI 1.3.3 the above code could both scroll and transform, but with Compose UI 1.4.0-rc01 only transform works, the scroll no longer works

I created an issue with Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273870226

In the meantime is there any way to work around this so that I can have both scrolling and transforming working at the same time?

Comment: I still experiencing same issue with compose 1.4.3 ? What about you ?

Comment: Sounds like the fix will be in 1.5 (which is in beta right now) so you could try that or you can copy and use the code from 1.3